# Haskell: padding out elements of a list

Tags: haskell

I have a list: `["1", "111", "11111", "1111111"]` and I would like to pad out each element with underscores to a length of 11 with the the original element in the middle i.e. `["_____1_____","____111____","___11111___","__1111111__"]`

I am using:

```
pad' x = s ++ x ++ s
  where 
    s = replicate ((11 - length x) `div` 2 ) '_'
```

is there a tidier/more efficient way to do this?

NB the required width will always be odd

Comment: Well `pad` does not work correct in case the number of characters in the string is odd.

Comment: If it's already working, [codereview.se] is a better site.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have edited my question. the required width will always be odd. See the expected output above

Comment: @matthias: but then it would not work in case the input string is even. If the difference of length of the string, and the expected length is odd, you can not split it over the two parts evenly.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes that is fine. The canvas will always have an odd width and the element in the middle that is to be padded out will itself always be odd.

Comment: You can, however, make either the leading or trailing pad `(div n 2) + rem n 2`.

Comment: @matthias: although you can of course add such contracts yourself. It is usually a good idea to not assume anything that is not enforced by the type system. After all, if the type system allows it, a programmer can call the function with all possible values. So in that case it is better to return something that makes sense.\

Answer (score 2):

Top level declarations should always have an explicit type.

I know that you say the total number of padding underscores will always be even, but it is never a good idea to build that kind of assumption into your code. Instead you should make your functions correct under all inputs if possible. That way you don't get hidden bugs when something changes and your assumption is no longer correct.

You should also make the padded width a parameter for the same reason. You can always create a specialized version as well.

Putting these things together, an improved version would be:

```
pad' :: Int -> String -> String
pad' n x = replicate s1 '_' ++ x ++ replicate s2 '_'
  where 
    len = length x
    s1 = (n - len) `div` 2
    s2 = n - s1 - len

pad11 :: String -> String
pad11 = pad' 11
```